# Gulp group media error "must start with number, buffer, array or string"

Tags: css, npm, gulp, media-queries

I use

```
var cmq = require('gulp-combine-media-queries')

gulp.task('cmq', function () {
gulp.src('css/style.css')
.pipe(cmq({
  log: true
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

And this error is output after gulp command:

```
File css/style.css found.
buffer.js:169
throw new TypeError('must start with number, buffer, array or 
string');
  ^

TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string
at fromObject (buffer.js:169:9)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:62:10)
at Transform.transform [as _transform] (/home/user/node_modules/gulp-
combine-media-queries/index.js:152:21)
at Transform._read (/home/user/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-
queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
at Transform._write (/home/user/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-
queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:12)
at doWrite (/home/user/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-
queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:237:10)
at writeOrBuffer (/home/user/node_modules/gulp-combine-media-
queries/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:227:5)
at Transform.Writable.write (/home/user/node_modules/gulp-combine-
media-queries/node_modules/readable-
stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:194:11)
at write (/home/user/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-
stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:623:24)
at flow (/home/user/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-
stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:632:7)
at DestroyableTransform.pipeOnReadable (/home/user/node_modules/vinyl-
fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:664:5)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:166:7)
at emitReadable_ (/home/user/node_modules/vinyl-
fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:448:10)
at emitReadable (/home/user/node_modules/vinyl-
fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:444:5)
at readableAddChunk (/home/user/node_modules/vinyl-
fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:187:9)
```

Node - 4.2.6, Gulp 3.9.1, npm - 3.5.2
I also used another npms for grouping media and have the same errors. I read many articles with the same problems, but none has helped

Answer (score 0):

looking at media-query code (https://github.com/konitter/gulp-combine-media-queries/blob/master/index.js)

I could see that your file "`css/style.css`" is not accessible by gulp hence the error.

Please recheck the path and try again